# How to refresh page after upload image on server. Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to refresh my page after upload image on server.

The problem is that after updating the profile image, the old image is displayed.
After restarting the application, a new profile image is appearing.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
// upload image on server..............
  upload() async {    
      var token = box.get('access_token');
      var stream = new http.ByteStream(Stream.castFrom(imgPath!.openRead()));
      var length = await imgPath!.length();
      var uri = Uri.parse(editProfileUrl);

      var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
        "Accept": "application/json"
        
      };

      request.headers.addAll(headers);
      var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('profile_pic', stream, length,
          filename: ("image_1.jpg"),
          contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png')
          );
         

      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      var response = await request.send();
      print(response.statusCode);
       if(response.statusCode == 200){
  
            showDialog(

              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Center(
                  child: AlertDialog(
                    
                    content: new Text("Your proflie has been updated successfully."),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      new ElevatedButton(
                        child: new Text("OK"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                           // redirect on main page......
                           // here i want to refresh my page to see updated image 
                           Navigator.push(
                            context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => MyMatrimony())); 
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run only the upload logic inside your function and return it's response from it.

Your function should look like this

```
// upload image on server..............
 Future<int> upload() async {    
      var token = box.get('access_token');
      var stream = new http.ByteStream(Stream.castFrom(imgPath!.openRead()));
      var length = await imgPath!.length();
      var uri = Uri.parse(editProfileUrl);

      var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
        "Accept": "application/json"
        
      };

      request.headers.addAll(headers);
      var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('profile_pic', stream, length,
          filename: ("image_1.jpg"),
          contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png')
          );
         

      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      var response = await request.send();
      print(response.statusCode);
    return response.statusCode;
```

And then, you can call the function from ui and take action after response

Your ui code should look like this

```
onTap: (){
upload().then((statusCode) {
 if(statusCode == 200){
                      setState(() {
                 
              )); 
            showDialog(

              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Center(
                  child: AlertDialog(
                    
                    content: new Text("Your proflie has been updated successfully."),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      new ElevatedButton(
                        child: new Text("OK"),
                        onPressed: () {
    
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
},
```

Comment: Same problem after update profile image, old image is still displayed. @batuhand